# How to do select from where variable is equal to multiple values?

Tags: sql

Here's a sample code:

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table where x.id=1 or x.id=2;
```

The idea is that I want to select the rows in which x.id is from 1 up to 80.

Comment: *x.id is from 1 up to 80.* formal : id <= 80 ?

Comment: @Selvin id <=80 might give you negative IDs, if there are any

Comment: yeah there is a chance but read again your coment: *negative IDs* ... really? who is using negative ID?

Comment: @Selvin yep, but i have seen legacy systems working with columns called ID and having negative numbers

Comment: Seriously? you wana continue this ... 1. I bet that he has no negative IDs(because his ID is AUTOINCREMENT) 2. it was just obvious example if he has negative IDs he should obvously take care of it...the point is that he don't know simple math/logic

Comment: how does it relate to Android at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM sample_table 
 WHERE x.id BETWEEN 1 AND 80
```

or

```
SELECT * 
  FROM sample_table 
 WHERE x.id IN (1,2,3.....,80)
```

depends on what you're going to do.
if it is always a range. use the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table where x.id>=1 and x.id<=80;
```